# How to Set a new class is not applied on Bootstrap and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

the point of the function is to make the column in a row bigger or smaller and do it by changing the class name by javascript.

The row and column is defined by Bootstrap's usually:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="myColumn" class="col-lg-5">
        <!-- Some Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if I set the classes of the element `#myColumn` there is no change neither visible or in the HTML.

I've tried the following:

1) `$element.attr("class", classes);`

2) `$element.prop("class", classes);`

3) `document.getElementById("myColumn").className = classes;`

4) `$element.attr("class", null); $element.attr("class", classes);`

5) Very awkward and ugly attempts to work-arround, but none was successful

There is no change applied at all, however if I run  command from the browser's console it runs as expected, but not from the script. The script is every time fresh, not cached.

Fun fact: When I do the following: `$element.attr("class", null);` the classes will disappear, but when I enter the class names, it's like the `.attr("class", null);` takes no effect and nothing happens.

Here are the snippets of the JavaScript code:

```js
var biggerCol = ($element) => {
    var newClasses = [];
    var classes = $element.attr("class").split(' ');

    for(var index in classes) {
        if(classes[index].startsWith("col-")) {
            var splitted = classes[index].split('-');
            newClasses.push("col-" + splitted[1] + "-" + (parseInt(splitted[2]) + 1));
        }
        else {
            newClasses.push(classes[index]);
        }
    }

    console.log(newClasses.join(' '));
    $element.attr("class", newClasses.join(' '));
};

var smallerCol = ($element) => {
    var newClasses = [];
    var classes = $element.attr("class").split(' ');

    for(var index in classes) {
        if(classes[index].startsWith("col-")) {
            var splitted = classes[index].split('-');
            newClasses.push("col-" + splitted[1] + "-" + (parseInt(splitted[2]) - 1));
        }
        else {
            newClasses.push(classes[index]);
        }
    }


    $element.attr("class", newClasses.join(' '));
}
```

As you can see the `console.log` the following is returned:

`col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-7 col-xs-13 column1 to-left-column als-vertical` which is as expected and correct to what I want.

My guess is that it has to do something with Bootstrap and jQuery combined.

Comment: Hey Tomas. Unfortunately the code in your question doesn't seem to replicate the issue you describe. https://jsfiddle.net/etpsdjL0/

Comment: Can you share how and where are you calling these functions? It is working perfectly here https://jsfiddle.net/90ux1jfz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up with a problem which was caused by calling both functions on the same selector which ended up like it showed no change, but it just kinda reseted itself.

The problem was a wrong selector in the second function (either smaller or bigger column).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the order by which the class are rank. One way to do it, is to put the `!important` tag in your custom CSS. However, you could try to add your custom class in the first position.

Tell me if you need more help!